# Join multiple tables with result set of another Query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, union

I need to join multiple tables along with the result set of a select query which itself uses a UNION operator to get data from two tables.
The following query is not giving any error but returns no data whereas the data exist. Please tell me what is wrong in this query. How can I achieve this.

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT max(a."TRIP_DATE" ),   
     max(a."TRIP_NUMBER" ),   
     max(a."BOOKING_NUMBER" ),   
     max(nvl(a."SPONSOR_ID",a."TRAVELLER_ID" )),
     max( EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ),
     max( FIRST_NAME ),
     max( MIDDLE_NAME ),
     max( SURNAME ),
     max(UPPER(nvl(a."SPONSOR_NAME",a."NAME" )) ),
FROM BOOKING a
JOIN SEGMENT_BOOKING b
ON a."BOOKING_NUMBER" = b."BOOKING_NUMBER" AND
    a."TRIP_NUMBER" = b."TRIP_NUMBER" AND
    a."TRIP_DATE" = b."TRIP_DATE" 
JOIN TRIP_SEGMENT c
ON b."TRIP_NUMBER" = c."TRIP_NUMBER" AND
    b."TRIP_DATE" = c."TRIP_DATE" AND
    b."SEGMENT_NUMBER" = c."SEGMENT_NUMBER"
JOIN ( SELECT d.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,d.FIRST_NAME AS FIRST_NAME,
        d.MIDDLE_NAME AS MIDDLE_NAME ,d.SURNAME AS SURNAME
        FROM STAFF d
        UNION
       SELECT e.CONTRACT_STAFF_ID,e.FIRST_NAME,e.MIDDLE_NAME,
        e.SURNAME
        FROM CONTRACT_STAFF e 
      )
ON a."TRAVELLER_ID"  = EMPLOYEE_NUMBER

     WHERE ( ( a."STATUS" = 'CF' ) OR ( a."STATUS" = 'WL' ) ) 
 AND  a."TRIP_DATE" >= TO_DATE('2014-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
AND a."TRIP_DATE" <=   TO_DATE('2015-05-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND  
             a."TRIP_NUMBER" like '%ABCDEFGH%' 
    GROUP BY a."BOOKING_NUMBER" ;
```

Comment: We don't have your data to validate and reproduce what you claim. Please post a working test case. Provide the create and insert statements. When you say you don't get any rows, then you need to look at your `filter predicate`. You must be filtering out the rows. Check your filter conditions.

Comment: Do you really want uncorrelated max values for first name, last name etc? That makes no sense at all to me...

Comment: If I remove the last join clause (the one with the subquery) I get around 13 rows which means the filter (Where clause) is returning 13 rows. The last Join clause(containing Select with UNION) is the issue here. Am I doing it right?

Comment: I need FirstName Lastname Surname in my result set. I am using max with them because of GroupBy clause else it will give me error.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this: "ON a."TRAVELLER_ID"  = EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" not sure if you can just access that subquery, have you tried aliassing it?

Comment: How can I alias it? If I alias the first UNION table x & second UNION table y, which one should I apply the join on? `ON a."TRAVELLER_ID" = x.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`     or     `ON a."TRAVELLER_ID" = y.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`   ???

Comment: `... e.SURNAME
        FROM CONTRACT_STAFF e 
      ) t
ON a."TRAVELLER_ID"  = t.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`

Comment: What you should be aliassing is your subquery result, not your tables, as @sqluser just showed

Comment: I aliased the subquery result as x & used the following condition but still no rows returned:      `...FROM CONTRACT_STAFF ) x
   ON a."TRAVELLER_ID"  = x.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`

Comment: Have you checked if your subquery returns any row?

Comment: I think I see the issue, I think you might want to alias your column e.contract_staff_id as EMPLOYEE_NUMBER (if I get what you are trying to do) because right now you are getting rows that have no value for employee_number because only the records of table STAFF have an employee number in the result, even if you would remove the union in the subquery your result would be the same as you are joining on employee_number

Comment: Is it necessary to have max for all the columns that you want to fetch?..... Just remove the max function for a.booking_number alone as you want to group it using booking_number and try.....

Comment: I got the result. After aliasing the UNION subquery as x alongwith adding TRIM in the JOIN condition. The reason I was not getting any rows even after aliasing it was because I was not using trim. Thanks alot for you help.

Comment: are you sure you are getting all the results from your union subquery you should be getting? you might want to check out my answer just in case, it might be another issue you haven't even noticed

Answer (score 0):

The issue might just be what your unioned subquery is returning

You have aliassed your column names for the STAFF table but not for the CONTRACT_STAFF table so only the results from STAFF table would have a non null value in EMPLOYEE_NUMBER field therefore your union subquery should be like:

```
SELECT d.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,d.FIRST_NAME AS FIRST_NAME,
                d.MIDDLE_NAME AS MIDDLE_NAME ,d.SURNAME AS SURNAME
                FROM STAFF d
UNION
SELECT e.CONTRACT_STAFF_ID AS EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
               e.FIRST_NAME AS  FIRST_NAME, e.MIDDLE_NAME AS MIDDLE_NAME,
                e.SURNAME AS SURNAME
                FROM CONTRACT_STAFF e
```

It might not solve all your problems but this is deffinitely one of them

Comment: I got the result set after applying trim & aliasing my subquery, Now I get 26 total rows wherease wthout this subquery I am getting 32 rows. 6 rows are missing from this result set.  Dont know why,after aliasing the second Union clause columns also as you have specified.

Comment: Got it, applied LEFT OUTER JOIN with my subquery, now getting 32 rows as expected, Thanks for your help.